# Adding attributes to img tag in Colorbox in WP

Tags: image, draggable, colorbox

I would like to add an additional attribute to each img tag in my Colorbox - specifically I would like to add: draggable="false".

I"ve already got the proper JQuery UI script and am using it on the gallery by adding the attribute in my NextGen Gallery install. If I could get the attribute added to the img tag within Colorbox life would be good.

The output from colorbox looks like this: img class="cboxPhoto" width="321" height="480" src="/wp-content/gallery/macros/02574_small.png" style="cursor: pointer; float: none;". If I add the attribute directly within the tag (using Firebug) it works; I just don't know where in the js to add that. (I'm not a Javascript nor JQuery expert by any standards.)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
- Colorbox: 1.3.19
- jQuery UI: 1.8.17
- jQuery: 1.7.1
- NExtGEN Gallery: 1.9.2
- Lightbox Plus: 2.4.6
- WP: 3.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this script to your document:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    jQuery('.cboxPhoto').attr('draggable', 'false');
});
</script>
```